# nested structure of various sourced repository living under a single GitHub repo

Tags: git, hadoop, github

There's a project I'm working on which involves a cluster of Hadoop nodes, each one with slightly different configuration files, specifically a `NameNode`, `SecondaryNameNode`, and `DataNode`.

What I'm trying to do is create one over-arching GitHub repository that can house each one of these different sets of directories, folder hierarchy, and files.

One way that I was thinking was just to create one repo where the different configurations are different branches.

**However**, is there another way to do this? Perhaps such that each node lives in a different sub-directory of the main repo? I could see how that might complicate the pushing and pulling.

Does anyone know what would be the best way to do this?

Here's a drawing of how I'd like it to be set-up:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Putting divergent code bases into a single repository can be troublesome. When you want to make a change that applies to all versions, merging it into all branches can be tedious and error prone.

I would design the system such that the configuration can be separate and passed into the code that uses it. Then, make 4 separate repositories:

- Main code
- NameNode config
- SecondaryNameNode config
- DataNode config

The config packages would each have the main code package as a dependency. Each could have a small amount of code to run the system in the main package, passing in its own config.

That way, you exercise code reuse effectively and avoid issues with multiple branches.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want some configuration management tool which can be used to deploy various configuration files.

First off, Apache Ambari or Cloudera Manager already do this for Hadoop. No reason to roll your own tool, in my opinion.

The other alternatives that I've been around use a Github repo for Chef/Puppet/Ansible modules/roles that are continuously deployed to the cluster. You can define variables at the overall environment level, per service, or just to particular hosts. And all configurations are in the master branch. You use host groups to specify which service or environment is applied to what servers